# How to set homepage based on device with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to set a default homepage based on the visitor device (mobile/desktop), I tried the following code in plugin, but did not work.

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
  $homepage = get_page_by_title( 'mobile' );
}else{
  $homepage = get_page_by_title( 'home1' );
}
if ( $homepage ){           
  update_option( 'page_on_front', $homepage->ID );      
  update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );                 
}
```

it keeps loading the home1, which is selected from theme options.

Thanks,

Comment: Is that the actual title of your pages? Or the slugs?

Answer (score 0):

Your current functionality wouldn't work, even if it "worked". You're attempting to set a site-wide option in the database based on the most recent visitor's device.

Using [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) isn't in your best interest here. What you should be doing is programmatically changing the template that's loaded at run-time based on the user's device, using the [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter - that way you're not storing a (semi) permanent change in your database, which would get constantly overwritten countless times by any user and affect all other users.

This would end up looking something like this:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'so_52745088_homepage_template', 99 );
function so_52745088_homepage_template( $template ){
    // Only execute on the front page, not pages/posts/cpts
    if( is_front_page() ){
        // Determine if mobile
        if( wp_is_mobile() ){
            // Make sure mobile homepage template is found
            if( $home_template = locate_template( array( 'homepage-mobile.php' ) ) ){
                return $new_template;
            }
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

If you don't have a separate page template for mobile, and it's just a regular ol' separate page, then you can look at using [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) on any number of hooks, a common one being [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect), which would end up looking like this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so_52745088_homepage_redirect' );
function so_52745088_homepage_redirect( $template ){
    // Only execute on the front page, not pages/posts/cpts
    if( is_front_page() ){
        // Determine if mobile
        if( wp_is_mobile() ){
            wp_safe_redirect( 'mobile' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but did not work! I have only a page, not a template.